# Raspbian cron running too late

Tags: php, mysql, cron, raspbian

On Raspbian, I have setup a script to run every minute through crontab -e:
* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/script

The script is a temperature logger. It reads the temperature from a sensor and writes the result to a (mysql) database.
A couple of times a day it doesn't start the script for about 8 minutes. Then the script is being started all the missing times. For example, the log shows me these times:

- 12.00.05 (normal)
- 12.01.06 (normal)
- 12.02.05 (normal)
- 12.10.08 (7 minutes late)
- 12.10.08 (6 minutes late)
- 12.10.08 (5 minutes late)
- 12.10.09 (4 minutes late)
- 12.10.09 (3 minutes late)
- 12.10.09 (2 minutes late)
- 12.10.09 (1 minutes late)
- 12.10.10 (normal again)
- 12.11.05 (normal)

There aren't any crons that run around the time the failures occur.
What can be the problem and how do I find or fix this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "failure"? What exactly happens? Could it be that whatever is failing is causing either cron or mysql not to execute too?

Comment: Hey Mike, thanx for your comment. There are no real failures. Maybe 'delayed script startups' would be a better word. All that happens is that the startup of the script gets delayed somehow and then all the delayed scripts get executed almost at the same time.